# How can I fix command line error supportedNodeVersions when deploying Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I upgraded firebase tools and after I updated the tools I get this error when I use any of the firebase commands.

Ex. firebase login or firebase deploy --only functions

```
/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/index.js:47
throw new Error(`@grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ${supportedNodeVersions}`);
^

Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/index.js:47:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:21:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

I have upgraded node

```
node -v
v10.5.0

npm -v
6.14.4
```

Even after upgrading everything I still run into this error. How can I fix this or is there another way I can deploy my functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following error message.

`Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0`

The Node version that you are using at local machine is `v10.5.0`.

If you want to use Node 10 then you should use `v10.10.0` or higher version(ex. v10.20.1).

```
nvm install v10.20.1
nvm alias default v10.20.1
npm install -g firebase-tools
```